# Conditional centering if single line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, conditionals

I would like to define a new environment that centers its contents if it can be typeset on a single line, but justifies the contents if it requires multiple lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{mycenter}{\noindent}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{mycenter}%
This should be centered since it is a single line
\end{mycenter}

\begin{mycenter}%
This should be justified since it is multiple lines. \lipsum[1]
\end{mycenter}

\end{document}
```

I have a convoluted idea using the [`Environ`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/environ) package to capture the contents, then sticking them in a box and trying to check the height of the box. Is there an easier way?

Comment: LaTeX's default `\caption` *macro* does exactly this. It works, but it may be that you're bound to typeset things more than once. Therefore, you have to be careful if the contents includes counter stepping or perhaps labels.

Comment: @Werner: Why not creating a box with the contents and centering *the box* if its width is less than `\textwidth` or `\linewidth`?

Comment: @krlmlr: The problem doesn't lie there. It lies with the resetting of the contents if it's greater than `\textwidth`, since setting it in a box doesn't have any text boundary and would require re-setting if wider than the text block. The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) apparently circumvents this.

Comment: @Werner: I see the issue for multiple paragraphs that all fit the desired width, but I'm not sure if that is a requirement. Single paragraphs can be typeset in a box justified and with restricted width; this box then can be centered if its width is smaller.

Comment: `environ` is what you're looking for. I'd measure the width, rather than the height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{mycenter}{\vbox\bgroup\bgroup
\parindent0pt\relax}{%
\par
\ifnum\prevgraf=1
\setbox0\lastbox
\noindent\hskip\parfillskip\hbox{\unhbox0}\par
\fi
\egroup\egroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{mycenter}%
This should be centered since it is a single line
\end{mycenter}

\begin{mycenter}%
This should be justified since it is multiple lines. \lipsum[1]
\end{mycenter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Why a double grouping? Also adding preceding and ending `\strut` makes for better alignment, no?

Comment: @Werner double grouping needed for colour safety (see grfguide) whether you need struts depends a bit on what you do with the box, whether you unbox it back on to the list or not.